# How to detect devices (usb/wifi)

Tags: macos

I have some confused, I know that for android is ADB that can detect devices that are connected across wifi and usb. For macos there are xcrun , but I dont know in which way I can work with real devices, and how detect devices that will connect across wifi...

For wifi device detecting ( may help ):
Ping the broadcast address (you can find it with `ifconfig | grep broadcast`) and then do an `arp -a`

Comment: You did not actually ask a question. Can you quote some code you actually tried, what the exact result was, and ask a question that starts, "How can I ___________ ?"

Comment: Open the Xcode app, in the status bar on the top navigate to "Window" and select "Devices", there you can manage devices connected via USB or WiFi

Comment: Thnx, but how can I do this with cmd ?

Comment: And when I use arp -a command I can see ip and mac address my tv device , but in Window-Devices there are only simulators

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in xcode version , I have 8.3 and it not support tv with 11 version